# Why does "This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly" exception happen on startup of the app?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget, nuget-package

I have developed a native Xamarin project and I'm now facing some problems with Xamarin.Android. Whenever I try to launch my application I come across the following exception and the app crashes. Here is the exception message:

> This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this
>   assembly.  You should reference the NuGet package from your main
>   application project in order to reference the platform-specific
>   implementation.

It had been working fine but suddenly I'm getting this message and I couldn't find any information about this on the web.

Comment: It tells you that you are using the portable (cross-platform) version of the library when you should be using a different library per platform. So please do.

Comment: but why this happens suddenly I didn't make any changes to packages,so How can I find which library causes this issue ?

Comment: how can i fix this issue ?

Comment: I don't understand ... switch to non-portable version of assembly .. I have PCL and I am uisng MVVMlight alogn with that .. do you mean I have to get rid of PCL ... Please explain me...  sorry for my ignorance

Comment: You are likely trying to write a dll, correct? In your main executable assembly that you are running to test your project you need to add the nuget package MVVMlight so it gets the correct stuff for your platform. If that works post the steps you had to do as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - I am not writing DLL... the code is just a PCL and I have nugets installed in both PCL and xamarin.android.

Comment: so I'm confused on how to debug and fix the issue ..... any ideas ?

Comment: I had this problem and a rebuild all fixed it. It was a PCL that wasn't available in non-portable versions. Totally misleading error message.

Comment: I had the same issue. Reinstalling the NuGet package in question solved it for me... The old question still remains, though: Why is Xamarin so buggy? (See: https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-Xamarin-platform-so-buggy)

Comment: can you remove the references from xamarin.android and re-add them and in the process make sure all the pcl versions referenced in PCL project has been added?